# Is String an Object in PHP?

Tags: php, string

Seeing other languages like Java or C++, String is an Object.
But in PHP is it the same thing?

Comment: PHP supports OOP, but is not fundamentally oop-based. strings are not objects in PHP.

Comment: You can actually have a string object in PHP with the SPL Types: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splstring.php ... but this is very new and very buggy

Comment: It's not natively an object but you could create your own string class if you wished. Just a few days ago I was thinking about this.

Comment: Is it the literal "String"? Or just a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string is not an `Object` in PHP. You don't have to cast the types of variables in PHP. See
http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php
and http://php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Ok so a string is a string I guess.

Comment: `$name = "John";` makes a String. PHP is much simpler than C(++) in this case. It tries to figure out what type your suggest.

Comment: So I need to write it string and not String. Sorry I like the conventions :-)

Comment: If you want you can write `$name = (string)"John";` or `$number = (int)"99";`

Answer (score 11):

A [String](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) is not an object in PHP by default and [casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)  is not required but it can be introduced if you want using [scalar_objects](https://github.com/nikic/scalar_objects)

```
class StringHandler {

    public function length() {
        return strlen($this);
    }
}

register_primitive_type_handler('string', 'StringHandler');
```

So you can easily have

```
$str->length();
```

Answer (score 3):

String is not an object in PHP; it's a primitive type. The information is on *[Types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php)*.

A lowercase string is correct for the few uses you might have.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*

Answer (score 3):

String and object are two different things. But if you wanted to run your own checks:

```
if (is_object($var))
{
 echo "Var is an object"; 
}
elseif (is_string($var))
{
 echo "var is a String"; 
}
else
{
  echo "var is neither an object or string"; 
}
```

Comment: I already did this test, but I wasn't sure if they just replaced the object kind by a string kind which it could had been itself an Object... That's the purpose of my question :-)

Comment: @user1682624 As a majority of the answers have stated, a string is not an object.. the same concept with an object being a string, the other answers provided are your solution

Comment: This isn't really an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everyting can be achieved via the built-in functions of PHP, so you can do all that you can with String objects.

Answer (score 0):

A string is not an object; it is a basic type.